# AuthorizationHandlerContext returns null User in custom Authorization Handler

Tags: authorization, handler, .net-core-3.0, claims, policies

I am trying to implement a custom authorization requirement, but it seems like context.User.Identity does not contain any data so the ClaimsPrincipal User.

- I added service and policy like this

  ```
   services.AddAuthorization(config =>
               {
                   config.AddPolicy("Test", policyBuilder =>
                   {
                       policyBuilder.UserRequireCustomClaim(0);
                   });
               });

   services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, TestHandler>();
  ```

my requirement, builder and handler are also set. How should I fix this problem in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem after a good rest and reviewing my code, i just extended my IdentityUser but didnt send it to base;

```
public ApplicationUser() : base() { }
```

so context couldnt be represented inside the handler. Problem solved...