# AuthorizationHandlerContext returns null for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions, authorization

Hi I have created a custom class to check for the claims a role has using AuthorizationHandlerContext class in asp.net core. When I debug, the current user always rns null.

The code is below.

`

```
internal class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public PermissionAuthorizationHandler(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
        {

            if (context.User == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Get all the roles the user belongs to and check if any of the roles has the permission required
            // for the authorization to succeed.
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
            var userRoleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var userRoles = _roleManager.Roles.Where(x => userRoleNames.Contains(x.Name));

            foreach (var role in userRoles)
            {
                var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
                var permissions = roleClaims.Where(x => x.Type == CustomClaimType.Permission &&
                                                        x.Value == requirement.Permission &&
                                                        x.Issuer == _configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"])
                                            .Select(x => x.Value);

                if (permissions.Any())
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`

I am trying to get the current user but it keeps returning null whenever I put a breakpoint in the code to check.

I am expecting to get the current user and user the user to retrieve the user's role and associated permissions.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and show the call stack when its null?

Comment: [Could you show more details about ApplicationUser ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964184/authorizationhandlercontext-returns-null-user-in-custom-authorization-handler)